# How can I make an image appear in Windows Forms C# when a specific value in ComboBox is selected?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I am trying to make a drop down list with several options ( educational majors ) and when the user selects a specific value ( educational major ) a study plan of that Major appears.

I already did the drop down list as follows:

```
InitializeComponent();
string i = "Information Technology";
string m = "Medical Lap";
comboBox1.Items.Add(i);
comboBox1.Items.Add(m);
comboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
```

And now remains the process when a value is selected an image related to that value appears.

Comment: Use one of the SelectedXXX events.

Comment: Appears where? Have you defined a Control where the Image should be presented? -- You can build a class object that associates each strings to an Image (or the Index of an ImageList or a Resource object or a File path, whatever fits). Use a `List<class>` to set the ComboBox.DataSource. When an Item is selected (SelectedIndexChanged or SelectionChangeCommitted), get the SelectedItem (cast it to your class object) and set the Image property of a, e.g, PictureBox, reading the Property that points to an Image in any way you have decided.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 2):

Based on your description, you want to show the correspond image when you select an item from combobox.

I suggest that you can use Dictionary to do it.

Here is a code example you can refer to.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var item in dic)
            {
                if(item.Key==comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString())
                {
                    pictureBox1.Image = item.Value;
                }
            }
        }
        Dictionary<string, Image> dic = new Dictionary<string, Image>();
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dic.Add("Information", Image.FromFile("D:\\1.jpg"));
            dic.Add("Medical", Image.FromFile("D:\\2.jpg"));
            dic.Add("Political", Image.FromFile("D:\\3.jpg"));
            dic.Add("biological", Image.FromFile("D:\\4.jpg"));
            foreach (var item in dic)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(item.Key);
            }
            comboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
            pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        }
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: `var cbo = sender as ComboBox; if (cbo.SelectedIndex < 0) return; pictureBox1.Image = dic[cbo.SelectedItem.ToString()];`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create an event handler that subscribes to the SelectedIndexChanged event of the combobox and inside of that event handler write the code that will display the proper image.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged?view=netcore-3.1

Answer (score 0):

if you created the combobox using VS once you double click on it creates the event handler for you , and attach it to the control, however if you need to add that manually you will need to do that in the initialize function see below

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }




private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.comboBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // comboBox1
        // 
        this.comboBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this.comboBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(174, 68);
        this.comboBox1.Name = "comboBox1";
        this.comboBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(121, 21);
        this.comboBox1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new 
     ***System.EventHandler(this.comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);***

 }
```

[Properties of the Combobox to assign event handler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHsxH.png)

after that you need to insert the code that will define the source of the picture box

example

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string picturelocation = "";
        picturelocation =@"c:\images\" + comboBox1.Text + ".jpg" ;
        pictureBox1.ImageLocation = picturelocation;
    }
```

where the combobox1.text will be your file names